# opening ms word using java not working when program exported as runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have used the below code for opening the .docx file placed in the eclipse project folder, i am able to open the .docx file if i run the program using eclipse but if i export the program as runnable jar file , program is not opening the .docx file. kindly provide some solutions for this.

```
   File userManual = new File("ToolGuide.docx");

    try {
        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(userManual);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

.docx file is placed in the below project folder structure in eclipse

Project Folder/ToolGuide.docx

Comment: is the docx in the same directory as the JAR ? If not you need to address it with a full path. And I hope that it is not included into the JAR because this for sure will not work too

Comment: Hi @Marged thanks for you response. .docx is in the same directory as other jars in the eclipse project, i tried to place the docx in a new source folder and give the path, its still not working when exported as runnable jar. I am sure that .docx gets exported with the runnable jar because the size of exported runnable jar is 2.3 MB ( with docx) and 2 MB (without docx) and size of docx ~ = 300KB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directory contents should look like this:

[image]

If you then start your application with `java -jar application.jar` the wordfile is positioned relative to your code and should open when you address it with `./wordfile.docx`.

Comment: Thanks, the above answer works for me. But not sure why we cannot package the file inside jar and open it.

Comment: This is because regular Windows applications are only able to open files that lie directly in a filesystem or are reachable by a URL (http). Word does know nothing about JAR files, the best it could do would be to open the jar file and show that content. It knows nothing about the internal structure and that somewhere in that file a word file is hidden. If your problem is solved you can accept the answer and / or rate it.